# ¿Cual es la mejor forma de separar la interfaz grafica de la aplicación?

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo una aplicación que corre a modo comandos sin interfaz grafica, en un ordenador sin pantalla. Esta aplicación procesa imágenes de una cámara conectada. A veces, necesito poder depurar lo que ve la cámara y lo que procesa el software, por lo que me gustaría poder levantar una interfaz grafica a distancia (web).

Por ahora, lo que se me ocurre es un patron publisher-subscriber donde la web simplemente se subscriba a todos los campos necesarios para hacer debug. Por ejemplo, esto lo puedo hacer utilizando ROS, pero no se si existen mejores maneras de hacerlo. A alguien se le ocurre alguna mejor manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Tengo la misma situación con ESP8266 y ESP32. Lo que hago es instalar un mini servidor web que atienda comandos incluidos en la URL (encender/apagar, etc). Los comandos incluyen consultas del estado del sistema, que se responden vía JSON. Con eso ya puedo implementar interfaces gráficas usando HTML o cualquier cosa capaz de hablar HTTP/JSON. Incluir la opción de enviar la imagen de vuelta (vía URL) es trivial.

Comment: En lugar de un mini servidor web, puedes usar MQTT, aunque requiere un broker externo. La gracia es que no necesitas HTML, CSS, JS ni nada. Puedes crear facilmente clientes en múltiples plataformas sin necesidad de codificar nada.

Comment: También puedes instalar el ambiente gráfico en el ordenador y conectarte vía VNC o algun protocolo similar. De esa manera sera como estar directamente en el ordenador. El ambiente gráfico lo puedes bajar cuando no lo necesites (al menos en Linux)

Comment: No conocia MQTT, me parece una buena opción, ya que me permite separar la GUI sin problemas. VNC no es una opción para mí, por la velocidad de conexión que tengo en el otro extremo.

Comment: Voy a ampliarlo y ponerlo como respuesta entonces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para aplicaciones que corren sin interfaz (gráfica o de texto), es posible usar MQTT como medio de control y consulta.

MQTT (Message Queuing Telemetry Transport) es un protocolo de red liviano para intercambio de mensajes entre dispositivos. Ha sido diseño con la IoT en mente.

Los actores:

- Broker. Es un servidor que recibe y distribuye mensajes entre los participantes.
- Clientes. Los clientes pueden publicar y suscribir mensajes.

Los mensajes se organizan en una jerarquia de tópicos y subtópicos (como "memoria/libre", "eth0/bytes_in", "/dev/sdb1/space"). El mensaje es simplemente un conjunto arbitrario de bytes, que los interesados sabrán como interpretar.

Cuando el broker recibe un mensaje, notifica a todos los subscritos a ese tópico para que lo lean.

Existen aplicaciones MQTT que permiten construir interfaces gráficas para leer y emitir estos mensajes. Estas aplicaciones están disponibles para Android, iPhone, Mac, Linux y Windows. Con ellas puedes construir interfaces como esta, sin programar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Brokers**

Hay [brokers públicos](https://www.hivemq.com/public-mqtt-broker/) que puedes usar sin trámite previo.

Opcionalmente puedes instalar tu propio broker (mosquitto es el estándar), para lo cual tienes opciones en todas las plataformas (incluido Android).